# Does Google Compute Load Balancer support traffic between projects?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Can I have HTTPS traffic be routed from Google Load Balancer in one project to NGINX running on compute instances in a different project? If so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

[HTTP(S) Load Balancer components](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/) have to be in the same project.